# Serializing System.Drawing.Color in .NET

Tags: .net, serialization

I've used the default .NET serialization for a class with a System.Drawing.Color member.  The code is now in use by people, and I need to add an extra member to the class, but still deserialize older versions.

So I tried the standard way of doing this: The ISerializable interface, using SerializationInfo methods to get the int and string members.

The problem: My class also has a System.Drawing.Color member, but SerializationInfo doesn't provide a "GetColor" method read this data type.  I've tried getting it as an int and as a string, and casting it to System.Drawing.Color, but no luck.

Does anyone know how to deserialize a System.Drawing.Color from SerializationInfo?

Answer (score 1):

Using ISerializable is not the recommended way to deal with versioning.  The [OptionalField] is, the ins and outs are well described in this MSDN [library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answering your question: SerializationInfo.GetValue("fieldName", typeof(Color)) ought to give you the color.  You'll need to cast the return value.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  Unfortunately [OptionalField] only works with the BinaryFormatter (I'm using the SoapFormatter).

Your GetValue suggestion compiled, but now I get the exception: "Top Object cannot be instantiated for element 'foreColor'"  (foreColor is the element I'm trying to deserialize.)

Any idea what causes this error, or alternate approaches?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have used something like this in the past.

```
 <Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore()> Public BackColour As Drawing.Color

        Public Property xmlBackColour() As Integer
            Get
                Return BackColour.ToArgb
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                BackColour = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(value)
            End Set
        End Property
```